# Puzzling change of language in windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus

I'm using WSUS on Windows Server 2012.

Initially the language was Italian.  I then switched to English.

In the list of services all are in English but one. There is still one that is listed "Servizio di registrazione W3C".  What is the English version of that service (maybe "W3C validation service"?)

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did any italian update on the server ? as it happen to me on french server, some added service are displayed in english when ither are in french.

Answer (score 0):

This is [W3C Logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814385(v=vs.85).aspx), the IIS logging service. The Italian translation is slightly too literal, I think...